# Linking records in Parse / Swift /iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm making an app where when unique records are added to a table in Parse by the end user.

1. When the first record is added, I want nothing to happen.
2. When the second record is added, I want it to link to the first record (so each record will have a col with the other records ID).
   Then third has no link, fourth links with third, etc.

What is the best way to do this?

**Edit:** Kind of like how Tworlds links photos. Needs to be close to real time (provided there is high volume) and notify both users that there is a match.

Comment: How do you know what number it is and what the number of the object to link to is? And is this parse.com?

Comment: Yes, parse.com. Please check the Tworlds app as this is what I mean. Basically two people add a record at the same time, and the system links them somehow

Comment: You're asking for magic, but no app uses magic. Explain how the other app works from a user perspective, are the users physically close to each other?

Comment: Both users upload a picture at roughly the same time. The app creates a logical link between the two pictures and sends back the other image. I'd like to do the same so: Two people upload a piece of text, which are records in a database. The two records are then linked together and the user is notified of the other record ID.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you should be able to achieve such functionality using Parse's `Cloud Code` module and `afterSave`, where you can write custom login in JavaScript.

Comment: But are the users physically close, or it's just random who you're connected to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you save a record in parse an afterSave function is called on the parse Cloud Code.

There You can query for all the recent added records to this class with -

```
query.find
```

You can order it by date or user or whatever.

```
query.ascending("userOrDate...");
```

Add the ID you need to your just saved object with -

```
request.object.set("otherPicID", IdFromObjectFromQuery);
```

save with -

```
request.object.save
```

make sure you check in the afterSave if this record is just created or updated (prevent loop) -

```
if (!request.object.existed())
```